# Is there anyway to disable this notification on google chrome (andorid)

Tags: android, google-chrome

Hey anyway to **disable** the floating in app notification for downloading, or download compleated notifications.
I tried all the settings i didn't find any.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to ur "Settings" in Chrome... Then "Notification"... Scroll down to find the "in app notification" settings option and turn it off✌

Comment: well, i tried disabling everything on the settings under notification. Also turned off notification for the chrome via Andorid settings. Still this thing still showing. And also i didn't find an option for the floating notification.In chrome